# How to use 1 atomic counter as a shared variable among multiple functions in GoLang

Tags: go

I am having 2 methods, one for createSession() and another for deleteSession().

These 2 methods are getting called by n no. of goroutines.

I want to use a atomic counter variable such that, if createSession() is called, the counter should get incremented by 1 on each call (can be incremented in the method) and in deleteSession where logoff api is called, there should be a check on the counter variable such that, if counter > 1, then don't logoff/delete the session as more than 1 threads have called createsession and if counter is 1 or less, then only logoff.

For this, I want to use a shared atomic counter. I am using a int32 var as an atomic counter.

Using following api to increment the counter inside createSession():

```
atomic.AddInt32(&counter, 1)
```

For comparing counter value in deleteSession, using following api:

```
if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&counter, 1, 0) == false {
        a10log.Info("Don't logoff as session is open")
        atomic.AddInt32(&counter, -1)
        return nil
}

if counter > 1 {
    a10log.Info("Not logging off the session")
    return nil
} else {
    a10log.Info("Logging off")
}
```

But I am not able to use the counter variable as a shared variable.

How can I share the value of counter in both the methods?

Comment: I want to decrement the counter only if it's not equal to 1.
Hence added the condition like
if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&counter, 1, 0) == false then decrement counter.

And if the counter value is 1 then just logoff, otherwise not

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, You can pass the address of variable `counter i.e & counter` to both the funcs. Package `sync/atomic`  is perfectly fine for this use case but If I were you, I will implement this use case using `mutex `

Comment: @PrakashP, I am using the counter variable of type int32, which is a variable in one structure for my usecase:

And I don't want to use mutex because I have to avoid locking.

Comment: Passing the variable address not working ?

Comment: When you use atomic operations to share values, it does not mean you can also share the variable without causing data races. Either use _only_ atomic operations, or synchronize access with a mutex.

Comment: Another point, atomic operations do not ensure order of operations, but when you have a statement like `if counter > 1`, it looks like you are trying to coordinate multiple goroutines. You will be better off using synchronization primitives that ensure ordering, like channels or mutexes, than trying to incorrectly re-implement them with atomics.

Comment: This is a java, C++ approach. In GO you don't share values among threads or processes, instead you create channels to communicate data to/from go routines.